# smb.conf file location on different flavors of Solaris

Tags: configuration, solaris, samba

Ok I am a total beginner with the Solaris Operating system and I need to install and configure samba on 3 boxes each has a different version of Solaris (8,9,10).

What I want to know location of samba configuration file i.e., `smb.conf` files in each version? So far all I have found is

1. Solaris 8

   > /usr/local/samba/lib/smb.conf
2. Solaris 9 and Solaris 10

   > /etc/sfw/samba/smb.conf

Is this right? I need to know where these files go by default when samba is installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba configuration files can be set anywhere your administrator want you to have them.

- `/usr/local/samba/` is the path where samba can be installed.
- smb.conf is one of the configuration files, along with private/secrets.tdb or username.map

You can launch your samba with a:

```
smbd -D -s /myPath/smb.conf
```

The two locations (samba installation and samba configuration paths) can be completely separate.

`-D` If specified, this parameter causes the server to operate as a daemon. That is, it detaches itself and runs in the background, fielding requests on the appropriate port. Operating the server as a daemon is the recommended way of running smbd for servers that provide more than casual use file and print services. This switch is assumed if smbd is executed on the command line of a shell.

`-s <configuration file>` 
The file specified contains the configuration details required by the server. The information in this file includes server-specific information such as what printcap file to use, as well as descriptions of all the services that the  server is to provide.

Answer (score 0):

The FILES section of the manpage for `smbd' may give some hints. I don't have any Solaris box handy, so cannot unfortunately confirm.

Answer (score 0):

you can do also the test parameter commands like this # testparm /etc/samba/smb.conf